# How to exclude the first item in a flexbox nowrap?

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a way to exclude the first item in a flex nowrap other than moving first element out of the container? I would like to have last three elements under the first element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">    
  <div id="tobeexcluded">abc</div>
  <div class="flexitem">content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

Fiddle of the actual container:
https://jsfiddle.net/vtax2bgf/6/

Fiddle of what I would like to reach (without moving first element out of the container): https://jsfiddle.net/4gefxk90/6/

Comment: enable the wrap and make the first element width:100%

Comment: @TemaniAfif I would like last three elements to lay always in one line. If I do what you propose, that requirement would not be fulfilled.

Comment: always 3 items under the first?

Comment: @TemaniAfif it should be unrelated to use case - if there would be 1000 elements - the scroll will appear. Let's say that the answer is: no.

Answer (score 1):

an inline-block configuration can do this, no need flexbox:

```css
.container {
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:auto;
  font-size:0;
}
.container * {
  font-size:initial;
}
#tobeexcluded {
  display:block;
}
.container > .flexitem {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">    
  <div id="tobeexcluded">abc</div>
  <div class="flexitem">some content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">some content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">some content</div>
</div>

<div class="container">    
  <div id="tobeexcluded">abc</div>
  <div class="flexitem">some content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">some content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">some content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">some content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">some content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">some content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">some content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">some content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">some content</div>
  <div class="flexitem">some content</div>
</div>
```